# Where are the EMR logs that are placed in S3 located on the EC2 instance running the script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, stdout, amazon-emr, stderr

**The question**: Imagine I run a very simple Python script on EMR - `assert 1 == 2`. This script will fail with an `AssertionError`.  The log the contains the traceback containing that `AssertionError` will be placed (if logs are enabled) in an S3 bucket that I specified on setup, and then I can read the log containing the `AssertionError` when those logs get dropped into S3.  However, where do those logs exist *before* they get dropped into S3?

I presume they would exist on the EC2 instance that the particular script ran on. Let's say I'm already connected to that EC2 instance and the EMR step that the script ran on had the ID `s-EXAMPLE`. If I do:

```
[n1c9@mycomputer cwd]# gzip -d /mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/s-EXAMPLE/stderr.gz
[n1c9@mycomputer cwd]# cat /mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/s-EXAMPLE/stderr
```

Then I'll get an output with the typical `20/01/22 17:32:50 INFO Client: Application report for application_1 (state: ACCEPTED)` that you can see in the `stderr` log file you can access on EMR: [image: image showing Log files section of EMR step]

So my question is: Where is the log (`stdout`) to see the actual `AssertionError` that was raised?  It gets placed in my S3 bucket indicated for logging about 5-7 minutes after the script fails/completes, so where does it exist in EC2 before that?  I ask because getting to these error logs before they are placed on S3 would save me a lot of time - basically 5 minutes each time I write a script that fails, which is more often than I'd like to admit!

**What I've tried so far:** I've tried checking the `stdout` on the EC2 machine in the paths in the code sample above, but the `stdout` file is always empty: [image: command terminal indicating that stdout is 0 bytes]

What I'm struggling to understand is how that `stdout` file can be empty if there's an `AssertionError` traceback available on S3 minutes later (am I misunderstanding how this process works?). I also tried looking in some of the temp folders that PySpark builds, but had no luck with those either. Additionally, I've printed the outputs of the consoles for the EC2 instances running on EMR, both core and master, but none of them seem to have the relevant information I'm after.

I also looked through some of the EMR methods for `boto3` and tried the `describe_step` method documented here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.describe_step - which, for failed steps, have a `FailureDetails` json dict response.  Unfortunately, this only includes a `LogFile` key which links to the `stderr.gz` file on S3 (even in that file doesn't exist yet) and a `Message` key which contain a generic `Exception in thread..` message, not the `stdout`. Am I misunderstanding something about the existence of those logs?

Please feel free to let me know if you need any more information!

Comment: my guess is aws is actually running the container somewhere else instead of on the emr master node.`docker ps` can find a running a container on master, yet I doubt it is the one in use. running `yarn application -list -appStates RUNNING` on master node can find one container, yet I can't access into it and I do not know if the `runtime log` can be found there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite normal that with log collecting agents, the actual logs files doesn't actually grow, but they just intercept `stdout` to do what they need. 
Most probably when you configure to use S3 for the logs, the agent is configured to either read and delete your actual log file, or maybe create a symlink of the log file to somewhere else, so that file is actually never writen when any process open it for write.

maybe try checking if there is any symlink there

```
find -L / -samefile /mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/s-EXAMPLE/stderr
```

but it can be something different from a symlink to achieve the same logic, and I ddint find anything in AWS docs, so most probably is not intended that you will have both S3 and files at the same time and maybe you wont find it

If you want to be able to check your logs more frequently, you may want to think about installing a third party logs collector (logstash, beats, rsyslog,fluentd) and ship logs to SolarWinds Loggly, logz.io, or set up a ELK (Elastic search, logstash, kibana)

You can check this [article from Loggly](https://www.loggly.com/blog/monitoring-amazon-emr-logs-in-loggly/), or create a free acount in logz.io and check the lots of [free shippers that they support](https://app-eu.logz.io/#/dashboard/data-sources/rsyslog)

Comment: Thanks! I will check that in a bit. That's also interesting re: log collecting agents.  I had suspected that this file never really exists in the way that I think of it - I think that may be the case if the symlink does not exist.